# How to .htaccess - Redirect only one page with out www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

htaccess - Redirect to with NOn www to www

it is fine fine but i want only particular page to open with out www how i have to open say me the solution it is like this
http://www.yourdomain.com/score/MarioRide/submit.php

i need above page  with out  WWW how i have to do pls help me like this

http://yourdomain.com/score/MarioRide/submit.php

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yourdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^score/MarioRide/submit.php$ http://yourdomain.com/score/MarioRide/submit.php [L,R=301]
```